# Error in assigning result of calling my method in a test + low coverage

Tags: apex, unit-test

WeatherController:

```java
public with sharing class WeatherController {
  @AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
  public static Map<String, Object> weatherCallout(
    String recordId,
    String uni
  ) {
    Account account = [
      SELECT BillingCity
      FROM Account
      WHERE Id = :recordId
    ];
    String bCity = account.BillingCity;

    HttpRequest httpRequest = new HttpRequest();
    httpRequest.setEndpoint(
      'https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=' +
        bCity +
        '&units=' +
        uni +
        '&appid=1040818432e64406295c1f5aaedba226'
    );
    httpRequest.setMethod('GET');

    Map<String, Object> newsJsonData = new Map<String, Object>();
    String strResponse = null;

    try {
      Http http = new Http();
      HttpResponse httpResponse = http.send(httpRequest);
      if (httpResponse.getStatusCode() == 200) {
        strResponse = httpResponse.getBody();
      } else {
        throw new CalloutException(httpResponse.getBody());
      }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
      throw ex;
    }

    if (!String.isBlank(strResponse)) {
      newsJsonData = (Map<String, Object>) JSON.deserializeUntyped(strResponse);
    }
    if (!newsJsonData.isEmpty()) {
      return newsJsonData;
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  }
}
```

mock :

```java
@isTest
global class MockHttpResponseGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {
    // Implement this interface method
    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {
        // Optionally, only send a mock response for a specific endpoint
        // and method.
        System.assertEquals('https://example.com/example/test', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('GET', req.getMethod());
        
        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"example":"test"}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

test :

```java
@isTest
private class WeatherControllerTest {
    @isTest
    private static void testWeatherCallout() {
        Account testAccount = new Account(Name='Test Account', BillingCity='San Francisco');
        insert testAccount;

        Map<String, Object> result = WeatherController.weatherCallout(testAccount.Id, 'imperial');

        System.assertNotEquals(null, result);
        System.assertEquals('San Francisco', result.get('name'));

        Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());
        // Error is on the line below
        HttpResponse res = WeatherController.WeatherCallout('0018d01230NEKgPAAX' , 'imperial');
        String contentType = res.getHeader('Content-Type');
        System.assert(contentType == 'application/json');
        String actualValue = res.getBody();
        String expectedValue = '{"example":"test"}';
        System.assertEquals(actualValue, expectedValue);
        System.assertEquals(200, res.getStatusCode());
    }
}
```

i have an error

> Illegal assignment from Map<String,Object> to System.HttpResponse

on `HttpResponse res = WeatherController.WeatherCallout('0018d01230NEKgPAAX', 'imperial');`

[image: coverage screenshot]

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple issues here.

The error you provided to us is itself pretty simple. You defined `WeatherController.weatherCallout()` to return a `Map<String, Object>`, not an `HttpResponse`.

So instead of

```java
HttpResponse res = WeatherController.WeatherCallout('0018d01230NEKgPAAX' , 'imperial');
```

you would need

```java
Map<String, Object> result = WeatherController.WeatherCallout('0018d01230NEKgPAAX' , 'imperial');
```

Just like the first call to that static method that you have earlier in your test. Hard-coding Ids is not good practice, and I can't think of what purpose it has here. This second call to your static method doesn't make much sense to me.

As written, you cannot get access to the HttpResponse from your mock callout. In tests, the stuff that you want to assert against is the stuff that's publicly visible to the client (i.e. the stuff using the code that you're testing). That's stuff like:

- The return value
- Records created/updated/deleted via DML
- Changes to public state (public instance and/or static variables)
- Exceptions that get thrown

So the HttpResponse isn't something you should (generally) be poking around in here. Instead, you want to make assertions that you either get an exception, or that the `Map<String, Object>` that you get back contains the expected data.

General suggestions:

- You should have multiple test methods, and have each one go down a slightly different execution path (one for the "happy path", one when the callout returns no data, one where your callout returns a non-200 code so you get an exception, etc...). If you test a sufficient number of scenarios, your coverage will naturally be high
- You need to have `Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseGenerator());` appear before you do any calls to `weatherCallout()`
- You should make your http mock constructor able to take parameters so you can control things like the data you get back and the status code
- That `try{ ...} catch(Exception e) { throw e; }` bit is useless. Just get rid of the try/catch altogether (i.e. get the stuff in the `try` block *out of the try block*)